# Table headers disappear

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, handsontable

I'm trying to make a table in React JS using Tabs Bootstrap.
When I switch to the second tab, the title of my second table disappears.
If, after switching to the second tab, click anywhere on the page, then the table headers will appear
Link screenshot https://prnt.sc/iFYRtvJnxzNg
My code:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css'
import {registerAllModules} from "handsontable/registry";
import {HotTable} from "@handsontable/react";
import {Container, Tab, Tabs} from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
    registerAllModules()
    const data = [
        ['', 'Tesla', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Ford'],
        ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];
    const headers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6']

    return (
        <div className="App">

            <Container>
                <Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="fill-tab-example" className="mb-3" fill>
                    <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
                        <div>123</div>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
                        <HotTable
                            data={data}
                            rowHeaders={true}
                            colHeaders={headers}
                            licenseKey='non-commercial-and-evaluation'
                        />
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab eventKey="longer-tab" title="Loooonger Tab">
                        <HotTable
                            data={data}
                            rowHeaders={true}
                            colHeaders={headers}
                            licenseKey='non-commercial-and-evaluation'
                        />
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Hey. did you try to init the Handsontable Component once a user clicks the tab instead of initializing it when the tab is hidden? This may be happening if your Tab has CSS 'display: none` set up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
Component initialization is successful, all data appears, only column headers do not appear

Comment: Hi, you can also use "mountOnEnter method in Tabs component and set it to "true". It will solve problems with rendering.

https://jsfiddle.net/aszymanski/fL9p7cm1/1/